# How plausible is it that pesticides and mosquito spraying is affecting insect populations?

Tags: biochemistry, entomology, pesticide

I live in Massachusetts and I notice that there are a lot fewer bugs than when I was a child. 40 years ago if you drove around for 4 or 5 hours in the summer the grill of your car would collect a noticeable amount of bugs. Nowadays, I can drive for the whole summer and there is not a single bug on my car. I rarely see a butterfly of any kind. I have not seen a monarch butterfly in years. When I was kid butterflies were omnipresent in any meadow or field. Even 20 years ago I remember cursing all those annoying Japanese beetles flying around. Haven't seen one in years. There used to be huge gypsy moth infestations. Even in off years, you would see the caterpillars plastered all over the sidewalks. Nowadays, sidewalks are all clean, not a single squashed bug.

I thought maybe this was because of mosquito spraying. In Massachusetts for many years we have had these huge mosquito spraying programs that cover every square inch of the state. The [method used is what they called ultra low volume spraying](https://www.cmmcp.org/services/faq/how-do-you-spray) or something like that. Even so, I can't see how it would be possible. For example, I saw a schedule for spraying in my county on an each day they would have 5 different towns listed. I don't see how a few trucks could possibly spray anywhere enough insecticide to depopulate 5 towns worth of bugs. I mean in my town alone there are probably a couple hundred roads and many areas that have no road access. How many roads can they possibly drive in one night? It doesn't seem possible, yet there no bugs.

Is there some kind of cumulative effect, or are these poisons so incredibly powerful that they just wipe everything out with even tiny amounts being released? How plausible is it that pesticides and mosquito spraying is affecting insect populations?